# Animating subviews in a stackview?

Tags: ios, spring, animation, uistackview

I'm trying to use the Spring animation framework to animate views within a stack view: https://github.com/MengTo/Spring

I understand how to get the animations working, but once I put my views into a stackview, the animations stop triggering.

I'm triggering the animations via an IBAction on buttons, and I've tried to create SpringButtons, and running the animation on a SpringView that holds the button as a subview. Neither options works.

Is it not possible to animate subviews of a stackview? Is the only option to layout each button individually with contraints?

Comment: I just did a quick test, and I can animate views contained in stack views without problem. Are you trying to do a minimal test? Or are you trying to incorporate the Spring animations into an existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out the Spring demo project and was able to wrap the animated view in a `UIStackView`.

[image: UIStackView with two SpringViews]
In this demo, it looks like they are keeping an `IBOutlet` reference to the `SpringView` within the `SpringViewController` like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ballView: SpringView!
```

It sounds like your situation may be different if you are populating the stack view dynamically, but holding a reference to your `SpringView` instances should allow you to animate them within a `UIStackView`.